# Sphinx - generate automatic references to Trac tickets and changesets

Tags: python, trac, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), is there way to automatically link text like `#112` or `r1023` to the corresponding tickets/changesets in [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)?

For eg:

```
#112  -> http://mytracsite/tickets/112
r1023 -> http://mytracsite/changeset/1023
```

See [TracLinks](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks) for more examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put this in your config.py

```
trac_url = 'http://mytratsite/'

from docutils import nodes, utils
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles
import urllib

def trac_role(role, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
  ref = trac_url + '/intertrac/' + urllib.quote(text, safe='')
  node = nodes.reference(rawtext, utils.unescape(text), refuri=ref, **options)
  return [node],[]

roles.register_canonical_role('trac', trac_role)
```

Then you can use `` :trac:`#123` `` and `` :trac:`r1023` `` in your documents.

This is probably the easiest way to make quick links to a trac site. It automatically works for all kinds of TracLinks because it uses the intertrac mechanism for the links.

Comment: Wow, adding roles is that easy? Cool! Only the register_canonical_role would look nicer as a @canonical_role decorator ;)

Comment: You can also use the `traclinks` role from the repository of contributed Sphinx extensions: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src

Answer (score 5):

Sphinx 1.0 now supports [external links](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/ext/extlinks.html) using the `extlinks` extension. Using a configurable role name (e.g. 'issue') you can write your links like:

```
:issue:`123`
```

and it will be converted to `http://mytracsite/123`.